# SQL Server - How to change table column only having some specific values?

Tags: sql-server

```
TABLE Family(
BrothersName varchar(30)
);
```

I have added some names (values) into BrothersName, but now I want it to only have 2 specific names `'Alex'` and `'Tom'`. However later it should also accept other names. What is the best way to handle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a **check constraint** stating `BrothersName` should accept only  `'Alex'` and `'Tom'`. In future when you don't need it you can drop the constraint

```
ALTER TABLE Family
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_BrothersName CHECK (BrothersName in ('Alex','Tom'))
```

To `Drop` the Check Constraint

```
ALTER TABLE Family
DROP CONSTRAINT chk_BrothersName
```