# SQL Server - Adding foreign key to a table

Tags: sql-server

As in my previous post ([linked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36506512/sql-server-how-to-change-table-column-only-having-some-specific-values)) I have been designing a table and I'm trying *to insert only some specific values* into the `BrothersName` column which can be done by adding a constraint.

```
TABLE Family
(
    BrothersName varchar(30)
);
```

However my question now is that I'm trying to do this instead by foreign key. Is the only way to do it is by making a new table and add primary key into it?

What can be the best way otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you should have a primary key table to hold all possible master data set for brother names like below

```
create table MasterBrotherNames (ID int  IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, Name nvarchar(30)) ;
insert into MasterBrotherNames(Name) values (N'Alex'),(N'Tom');
```

Now you should hold foreign key ID into the `Family` table as int, say in column `BrothersNameID` using following query to create FK relationship

```
create table Family( BrothersNameID int NOT NULL);
alter table Family add constraint fk_family_brothername foreign key ( BrothersNameID ) references MasterBrotherNames (ID);
```

To test out try queries below

```
insert into Family values (1)-- for Alex
insert into Family values (2)-- for Tom
insert into Family values (3)-- this gives error
--The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "fk_family_brothername".
```

Based on OP's following request

> is there any way to implement this without having any Id in MasterBrothersName, where only names can be inserted and accepted as values

here's the modified query

```
create table MasterBrotherNames ( Name nvarchar(30) PRIMARY KEY) ;
insert into MasterBrotherNames(Name) values (N'Alex'),(N'Tom');

create table Family( BrothersName nvarchar(30) NOT NULL);
alter table Family add constraint fk_family_brothername foreign key ( BrothersName ) references MasterBrotherNames (Name);

insert into Family values (N'Alex')-- for Alex
insert into Family values (N'Tom')-- for Tom
insert into Family values (N'A')-- this gives error
--The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "fk_family_brothername".
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond. This one is a little bit harder for me to understand, but is there any way to implement this without having any Id in `MasterBrothersName`, where only names can be inserted and accepted as values? such as `insert into Family (BrothersName) values ('Alex')`

Comment: @Tomb_Raider_Legend Sure. Updated.